# How do I find the p-value for my random effect in my linear mixed effect model?

Tags: r, lme4, p-value

I am running the following line of code in R:

```
model = lme(divedepth ~ oarea, random=~1|deployid, data=GDataTimes, method="REML")
summary(model)
```

and I am seeing this result:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: GDataTimes 
      AIC     BIC   logLik
  2512718 2512791 -1256352

Random effects:

 Formula: ~1 | deployid
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    9.426598 63.50004

Fixed effects:  divedepth ~ oarea 
                Value Std.Error     DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 25.549003  3.171766 225541  8.055135  0.0000
oarea2      12.619669  0.828729 225541 15.227734  0.0000
oarea3       1.095290  0.979873 225541  1.117787  0.2637
oarea4       0.852045  0.492100 225541  1.731447  0.0834
oarea5       2.441955  0.587300 225541  4.157933  0.0000

[snip]

Number of Observations: 225554
Number of Groups: 9
```

However, I cannot find the p-value for the random variable: `deployID`. How can I see this value?

Comment: Generally if you are fitting a mixed effect model, you're not trying to get a p-value for your random effects, you're just trying to adjust for them. Exactly what test do you want to perform to generate a p-value? What hypothesis do you want to test? If you need statistical advice, you should seek help at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: I agree this is a question that may be more suited to Cross Validated. The R-based [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) that Ben Bolker and others maintain is often a useful place to check when running into these sorts of questions. Here's the section on testing of random effects: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there is stuff about significance tests of random effects in the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects). You should definitely consider:

- why you are really interested in the p-value (it's not *never* of interest, but it's an unusual case)
- the fact that the likelihood ratio test is extremely conservative for testing variance parameters (in this case it gives a p-value that's 2x too large)

Here's an example that shows that the `lme()` fit and the corresponding `lm()` model without the random effect have *commensurate* log-likelihoods (i.e., they're computed in a comparable way) and can be compared with `anova()`:

Load packages and simulate data (with *zero* random effect variance)

```r
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x = rnorm(120), f = factor(rep(1:3, 40)))
dd$y <- simulate(~ x + (1|f),
                 newdata = dd,
                 newparams = list(beta = rep(1, 2),
                                  theta = 0,
                                  sigma = 1))[[1]]
```

Fit models (note that you **cannot** compare a model fitted with REML to a model without random effects).

```r
m1 <- lme(y ~ x , random = ~ 1 | f, data = dd, method = "ML")
m0 <- lm(y ~ x, data = dd)
```

Test:

```r
anova(m1, m0)
##    Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test      L.Ratio p-value
## m1     1  4 328.4261 339.5761 -160.2131                            
## m0     2  3 326.4261 334.7886 -160.2131 1 vs 2 6.622332e-08  0.9998
```

Here the test *correctly* identifies that the two models are identical and gives a p-value of 1.

If you use `lme4::lmer` instead of `lme` you have some other, more accurate (but slower) options (`RLRsim` and `PBmodcomp` packages for simulation-based tests): see the GLMM FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ben and others. I didn't believe I needed the p-value for the random variable, but was told to present it which had me confused. I just had to demonstrate that including the random effect in the model provided a better model than without the random effect. All you are saying makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: if this answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it

Comment: One last quick question, do you know why all my degrees of freedom are the same? Including the one for the intercept?

Comment: My guess is that it's because you have all numerical covariates. The precise description of `lme`'s df-computation algorithm is reproduced [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have) (search for "page 91")